# How to remove a specific element from the list of Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a Dictionary

```
Dictionary <String, List<Object>> myDictionary;
```

What is the best way to update Dictionary so that one of the Object from the list will be removed by known key. For instance I want to remove third object from the list.
Remove will remove value by specific key. So it will remove the whole list corresponding to the key. And I want to update the list that is inside of the dictionary.

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully provide a solution to your problem. If you need any further assistence, please let me know.

Comment: Thank You Markus. that was helpful.  Is it possible to do the same using Lambda Expressions ?

Comment: In a safe way, not to my knowledge. You could use something like `dict["key1"] = dict["key1"].Where((item, index) => index != 3).ToList();` but that would require that the _key_ must exists (or you will get an _KeyNotFoundException_). So this is not a robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2) Method.

```
myDictionary.Remove("key");
```

According to the documentation the method returns:

> true if the element is successfully found and removed; otherwise, false. This method returns false if key is not found in the Dictionary.

**Update:**

According to your updated question, you want to remove an element within the list which would mean getting the value of the dictionary first, afterwards changing an element within that value (which is a list in your case). So you can use the [`RemoveAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of the list there.

```
List<Object> values;

if (myDictionary.TryGetValue("key", out values))
{
  // Here you have access to the list by using values, therefore you can modify your list here
  // Make sure, that the list really contains an element at index 3
  if (values.Count > 3)
      values.RemoveAt(3);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, how does this answer **update Dictionary so that one of the Object from the list will be removed**?

Comment: @ErikPhilips: It didn't because when I first answered the question the OP did not state that he wanted to remove an element **in the list**. The question was updated after I answered - I have updated my answer too ;-)

Comment: Based on viewing the [history of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53309955/revisions) which everyone can do, the question itself hasn't changed....

Comment: @ErikPhilips, you are right, seems I had read too fast then... I was sure there was nothing stated about the object in the list but it is pretty late at my site - may I should go to bed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> update Dictionary so that one of the Object from the list will be removed?

First you need to retrieve the `List` from the dictionary, for example you can use the key.  It would be something like:

```
if (myDictionary.TryGetValue("key", out List<Object> value)) {
  value.RemoveAt(2);
}
```

You can use [TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the value based on your key (and if it exists, then you can get the `List<object>` reference.

Since the reference for `value` in the above example is the same reference the `Dictariony<>` uses, you can use [List.RemoveAt(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=netframework-4.7.2) to remove the 3rd on from the list.

Comment: Voting for this answer and OP has commented about: `Remove will remove value by specific key. So it will remove the whole list corresponding to the key. And I want to update the list that is inside of the dictionary.`

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi It's quite often people don't read the question and make write asnwers based on assumptions that actually don't answer a question.